# Cross database joins taking more time then expected

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 tables in 2 different Databases, both are on same server. I run a join on 2 and it takes more then 8 minutes to get results.

```
CREATE TABLE `ps_product_attribute` (  
    `id_product_attribute` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    `reference` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `supplier_reference` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `location` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `ean13` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `upc` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `wholesale_price` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',  
    `price` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',  
    `ecotax` decimal(17,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',  
    `quantity` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `weight` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',  
    `unit_price_impact` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',  
    `default_on` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `minimal_quantity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
    `available_date` date NOT NULL,  
    `attribute_color` varchar(10) DEFAULT '#FFFFFF',  
    `swatch_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_createddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_createdby` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_modifieddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_modifiedby` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_product_attribute`),  
    KEY `product_attribute_product` (`id_product`),  
    KEY `reference` (`reference`),  
    KEY `supplier_reference` (`supplier_reference`),  
    KEY `product_default` (`id_product`,`default_on`),  
    KEY `id_product_id_product_attribute` (`id_product_attribute`,`id_product`),  
    KEY `ps_product_attribute_ean13` (`ean13`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143326 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and second table in another database.

```
CREATE TABLE `t_stockreserves` (  
    `a_stockreserveid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `a_ean` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_basemarketplacereserve` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_marketplacereserve` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_criticalreserve` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_createddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_createdby` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_modifieddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
    `a_modifiedby` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`a_stockreserveid`),  
    UNIQUE KEY `t_stockreserves_ean_ind` (`a_ean`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16855 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

i just run a query like below

```
SELECT ps_product_attribute.id_product
 FROM ps_product_attribute 
LEFT JOIN `dropship`.`t_stockreserves` ON `t_stockreserves`.`a_ean` = `ps_product_attribute`.`ean13`
```

it takes 8 minutes to run the query. Here is the explain command output

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  ps_product_attribute    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    125960  
1   SIMPLE  t_stockreserves     index   NULL    t_stockreserves_ean_ind     16  NULL    17083   Using index
```

Is there any problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

How about different CHARSET for tables and joining with VARCHAR?

I would test it with tables having the same charset.

Comment: will give it a try with same charset and see